# Conditioning on independent random variables

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, inference, conditional-expectation

I am in a situation where I have to compute:

$$E(u(x_1)|\bar{X},S^2)$$

where $X_1$ is a normally distributed random variable and $u(.)$ some function. I know that by the student's theorem the sample mean and the sample variance are independent and moreover that $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2 (n-1)$.

Can I simplify the expectation with the information I possess? Is perhaps the bivariate normal distribution of use here?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Yes, an iid sample on $X$ is assumed here, hence the subscript $1$ on $u(x_1)$. If the expectation cannot be simplified, what is the conditional distribution of $X_1$ given $\bar{X}$ and $S^2$?

Comment: I assume there is an i.i.d sample somewhere in the back. Try a 2nd order Taylor Expansion around the sample mean.

Comment: Also, treat $X_1$ and $\bar X$ as two correlated normal rv's, calculate their correlation, etc

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos  $u(x_1)=u(\bar{x})+u\prime (\bar{x}) (x_1-\bar{x})+u\prime \prime (c)(x_1-\bar{x})^2 /2$. But what will I get out of that? Are you perhaps suggesting replacing $u(x_1)$ with its taylor expansion? If so, what would be the benefit? Sorry I am completely stuck here.

Comment: But what you want is the _expected value_ of the Taylor expansion, _conditional_ on...

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos It's still a conditional expectation which I do not know how to handle. For example, how would I take the expectation $E(u(\bar{x})|\bar{X},S^2)$?

Comment: @Glen_b Hello Glen. This is a corollary of the t-distribution and simply says that the sample mean and the sample variance are independent. Student refers to William Gosset who published it under that pseudonym.

Comment: He did? Where and when?

Comment: @Glen_b In the early 20th century http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Gossett. Recall that the t-distribution is defined by $t=\frac{W}{\sqrt{V/r}}$ with $W\sim N(0,1)$ and $V \sim \chi^2 (r)$ , $W$ and $V$ independent! His contribution is an example of how beer moves the world.

Comment: @Glen_b You can consult Hogg and Craig, 7th edition, page 193.

Comment: I've managed to find reference to it in some documents online (e.g. [here](http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/goodman/teaching/RPME/notes/Section2.pdf)) but at that link what they call 'Student's theorem' is this: "Student noticed that the probability density of $t$ depends on $n$ but not on the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$."

Comment: @Glen_b There are several aspects to the student's theorem, as presented in Hogg and Craig. One is that the sample mean and the sample variance are independent. Another is that the sample mean of a normal population is normally distributed and then, because of these implications, the quotient $T=\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ has a t-distribution with $n-1$ df. So although, it is not the exact same phrasing the other authors use, I do not see any contradiction.

Comment: How is $X_1$ related to $\overline{X}$ and $S^2$?  Your comment about wanting to understand $E(u(\overline{X})|\overline{X},S^2)$ is confusing.  That is just $u(\overline{X})$ unless you meant two different samples of the mean.

Comment: @MathEE I do not understand your point. There is only one sample.

Comment: I mean the probability of $A=c$ given $A=a$ and $B=b$ is either zero or one depending on whether or not $a=c$.

Comment: @MathEE If you have a solution, please post it then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the information in the question, we have a sample of $n$ i.i.d normals (which also means that their joint distribution is also normal), each following $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Therefore $\bar X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$.
One can easily calculate that $\operatorname{Cov}(X_1, \bar X) = \sigma^2/n$. So their correlation coefficient is $\rho = 1/\sqrt{n}$. Then, since their joint distribution is bi-variate normal, the conditional expected value of $X_1\mid \bar X$ is

$$E(X_1\mid \bar X) = \mu + \rho \frac{\sigma}{\sigma/\sqrt n}(\bar X - \mu)= \bar X$$.

...as should be expected
Now the reason I mentioned in the comments a 2nd-order Taylor expansion, is the completely arbitrary nature of $u(\cdot)$, which does not really permit us to do anything much. But with the Taylor expansion around the sample mean, we have (write $M$ for $\{\bar X, S^2\}$)

$$E(u(X_1)\mid M)\approx E\Big(u(\bar{X})+u^{\prime} (\bar{X}) (X_1-\bar{X})+\frac 12u^{\prime \prime} (\bar X)(X_1-\bar{X})^2\mid M\Big)$$

Since when we condition a function of a random variable on the random variable, we have $E(u(Y)\mid Y) = u(Y)$, $E(Y \mid Y) = Y$, $E(ZY\mid Y) = YE(Z\mid Y)$ in our case this implies

$$E(u(X_1)\mid M) \approx u(\bar{X})+u^{\prime} (\bar{X}) (E(X_1\mid M)-E(\bar{X}\mid M))+\frac 12u^{\prime \prime}(\bar X)E\Big[(X_1-\bar{X})^2\mid M\Big]$$
and using the previous results, the second term is zero, and so we obtain

$$E(u(X_1)\mid M) \approx u(\bar{X})+\frac 12u^{\prime \prime}(\bar X)E\Big[(X_1-\bar{X})^2\mid M\Big]$$

But
$$E\Big[(X_1-\bar{X})^2\mid M\Big] = \text{Var}(X_1\mid M) = S^2$$ so

$$E(u(X_1)\mid M) \approx u(\bar{X})+\frac 12u^{\prime \prime}(\bar X)S^2 \qquad [1]$$

Of course, one should deal also with the Remainder (the expected value of it). The "Peano form" of the Remainder is the most convenient here, meaning that we need to consider
$$E[R_2(X_1;\bar X) \mid M]=E\left[h_2(X_1)\cdot \left(X_1-\bar X\right)^2 \mid M\right] \qquad [2]$$

where $h_2()$ is some function with the property that $h_2(X_1) \rightarrow 0$ as $X_1 \rightarrow \bar X$.

Then, take the full Taylor expansion of $h_2()$ around $\bar X$ using again the peano form to write this Remainder too:

$$h_2(X_1) = h_2(\bar X) + h_2'(\bar X)(X_1-\bar X) + g_1(X_1)\cdot (X_1-\bar X)$$

$h_2(\bar X) = 0$. Insert the rest into eq. $[2]$ to obtain:

$$E[R_2(X_1;\bar X) \mid M]=E\left[\Big(h_2'(\bar X)+ g_1(X_1)\Big)\cdot\left(X_1-\bar X\right)^3 \mid M\right]$$

$$=h_2'(\bar X)E\left[\left(X_1-\bar X\right)^3 \mid M\right] + E\left[g_1(X_1)\cdot\left(X_1-\bar X\right)^3 \mid M\right]$$

The conditional on $M$ distribution of $X_1$ will also be normal, and has mean $\bar X$ as we have seen. So the third central moment, being odd, will be zero. Then the 1st term in the above expression is zero and we are left with

$$E[R_2(X_1;\bar X) \mid M]= E\left[g_1(X_1)\cdot\left(X_1-\bar X\right)^3 \mid M\right] \qquad [3]$$

which I would say, will be a rather small amount, since $g_1$ belongs to the Remainder of the Remainder.

Note that if we can say that $u'''(X_1)$ is bounded above and below in a neighborhood of $\bar X$ and belongs to the interval, say $[a, A]$ then the expected value of the Remainder is sandwiched to zero, because we have

$$a\frac {(X_1-\bar X)^3}{3!} \le R_2(X_1;\bar X) \le A\frac {(X_1-\bar X)^3}{3!}$$

$$\Rightarrow E\left (a\frac {(X_1-\bar X)^3}{3!} \mid M\right) \le E[R_2(X_1;\bar X) \mid M] \le E\left (a\frac {(X_1-\bar X)^3}{3!} \mid M\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow 0 \le E[R_2(X_1;\bar X) \mid M] \le 0 \Rightarrow E[R_2(X_1;\bar X) \mid M]=0$$

If we cannot say anything about $u()$ then we are left with the approximation $[1]$ and the approximation error $[3]$.

Comment: Your answer, covers my question and provides isnightful hints as well. I will keep the question open until bounty expires in case anyone else wants to contribute.